# What is the command to see what files in linux is currently being written or read?

Tags: filesystems, top, unix-utils

Just like top command which tells what process is running in the system and what is it doing like
which process is running and taking CPU. I want to know in the running system what currently the system is doing with the file like where is it writing in the disk space? I don't want to use watch command since I am talking about the entire system like currently where in the entire filesystem any file is being read or written. If reading is not available then I am fine but writing is definitely important for me.
I am trying to check the health of they system and I want to monitor what files are being written to the file system currently.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an inotify watcher on the entire file system.  You may need to increase the number of permitted watchers https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers

Some other things which may be of use:

- `iotop` can show you which processes have the most I/O activity
- if you identify a particular process that you want to see what it's writing to, you can use `strace` on its process ID I believe